# Send a tag in a url

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, url

First, sorry for my english it's not my native language.

So, I am working on an application in JSP and in one of my forms I have a field "comments". When I submit this form, the value of this field is sent to my servlet by an ajax request.

```
var request = 'mainServlet?command=SendRequest';
request += ('&comments=' + $('#comments').val());
```

But when there is a "<" or ">" in the field, $('#comments').val() translate them into "&lt" or "&gl". For exemple,  is converted to &lt ;test&gl ;

And when I want to recover the value in my servlet, I do:

```
String comments = request.getParameter("comments");
```

But the url looks like : `mainServlet?command=SendRequest&comments=&lt ;test&gl ;`

So request.getParameter("comments"); returns an empty string.

I thought that I could replace the string like &lt by my own code and then replace it again in my servlet, but is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks.

Edit: After, I reuse the comments in an other jsp.

Comment: Why are you sending the comment data as query String to begin with?

Comment: I join the project after the others began, and they send the others parameter of the form using this method. So I've continued this way.

Comment: Don't do that. POST the information, don't use GET for this. If that's really not possible, URL encode the parameters. But POST is preferred.

Comment: @ErikPragt by OP's last comment, I don't know if OP needs to learn the HTML concepts or everybody in his/her team...

Comment: Splendiferous give me the solution but thanks Luigi and Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you need is the [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function. It will convert any string into a format that you can use inside a URI.

Just remember to decode it on the receiving end, I believe the [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) class can do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna try

Comment: Perfect, it's working. I didn't use URLDecoder class because i reuse the comments in antoher jsp page and < and > are perfectly displayed, thanks.